# Translation: Some parts missing

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am trying to translate:

"Do you have time to read?" and end up with: "у вас есть время, чтобы прочитать?". Is there any other way to re-phrase the second part of the sentence?
Would "у вас есть время, читать?" work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"У вас есть время, чтобы прочитать?" means 'Do you have time to finish reading it?' since "прочитать" is a perfective verb meaning 'to begin and finish reading something'.
Your variant "У вас есть время читать?" is OK, only the comma is not needed there. Also you can say it as "У вас есть время на чтение?" that is 'Do you have time for reading?'

Answer (score 3):

That depends upon what you're trying to say.

> *У Вас есть время, чтобы прочитать?* --> Do you have time to read [this book]?; i.e. you ask if the person minds reading some text
>
> *У Вас есть время, чтобы читать?* --> Do you have time to read? [Really?]; i.e. you believe that the person is too busy to read anything at all
>
> *У Вас есть время, чтобы почитать?* --> Do you have time to read [a little]; this is mostly neuter, as it may mean both above.

Comment: The first variant sounds incomplete, because "прочитать" normally needs a direct object.

Comment: @codeholic Yes, it's elliptical construction. I didn't bother to add "[this book]" to both parts.